# splitting column in many rows gives too many rows

Tags: oracle

I am trying this statement

```
with value_table as
(select 1 id, '1/2/3' objnr from dual
union all 
select 2, '4/5/6' from dual),
 test as
(select id, objnr col from value_table  where id in (1, 2))
    select id, regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+', 1, level) result
    from test 
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^/]+')) + 1
    order by 1
```

I want to get 6 rows

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
```

but I am getting the rows multiple times.
When I try it with just one id, it works without a problem.
As a workaround, I just made a loop for every single id, another solution is to use distinct, but that takes ages to execute, when I try it, with real data(over 1000 entries).
Can someone provide a more sophisticated solution?

Answer (score 1):

try distinct as used below

```
with value_table as
(select 1 id, '1/2/3' objnr from dual
union all 
select 2, '4/5/6' from dual),
 test as
(select id, objnr col from value_table  where id in (1, 2))
    select distinct id, regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+', 1, level) result
    from test 
    connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '[^/]+')
order by 1
```

tried with sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03d80/14

**EDIT:**

If you don't want distinct try the below

```
with value_table as
(select 1 id, '1/2/3' objnr from dual
union all 
select 2, '4/5/6' from dual),
 test as
(select id, objnr col from value_table  where id in (1, 2))
    select id, regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+', 1, level) result
    from test 
    connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '[^/]+')
 and id = prior id
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
order by 1
```

which uses the model clause `PRIOR` the sqlfiddle link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03d80/31

Comment: As stated in the question. distinct is not a valuable solution, when I use real data.

Answer (score 1):

This query is executed

```
with test as
(
select 1 id, '1/2/3' objnr from dual union all
select 2 id, '4/5/6' objnr from dual 
)
select id, regexp_substr (objnr, '[^/]+', 1, rn) result
from test
cross
join (select rownum rn
       from (select max (length (regexp_replace (objnr, '[^/]+'))) + 1 mx
               from test
            )
     connect by level <= mx
     )
where regexp_substr (objnr, '[^/]+', 1, rn) is not null
and id in (1, 2)
order by id,result ;
```

---

ID                     RESULT

---

1                      1
1                      2
1                      3
2                      4
2                      5
2                      6

If you use Oracle 11g, you can also use REGEXP_COUNT instead of the combination of REGEXP_REPLACE and LENGTH, which would look like this:

```
cross
join (select rownum rn
    from (select max (regexp_count (objnr, '/') + 1) mx
            from test
         )
 connect by level <= mx
 )
```

to have outer join behaviour so made a slight variation as below:

```
with test as
  (
  select 1 id, '1/2/3' objnr from dual union all
  select 2 id, '4/5/6' objnr from dual 
  )
  select id, regexp_substr (objnr, '[^/]+', 1, rn) result
    from test
    left outer join (select rownum rn
           from (select max (regexp_count (objnr, '/') + 1) mx
                   from test
                )
         connect by level <= mx
         ) splits 
    ON  splits.rn <= length(regexp_replace (objnr, '[^/]+'))+1    
   and id in (1, 2)
   order by id,result ;
```

Comment: it works, but I am still wondering if there is a better solution.